# VS2010 almost always zooms text on scroll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scroll, zooming

You know the neat text zoom feature in VS2010 where you hold down Ctrl and then use your scroll wheel? Well, this seems to happen by default (and without ever pressing Ctrl) to nearly every file I open.

Usually I open a file and have to scroll to some lower point, but instead it starts zooming the text! I have found that by tapping the Ctrl key VS then realizes that it should scroll instead of zoom, but it's still very annoying.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this ever happen in other programs that support Ctrl+Scroll? Are you using remote desktop?

Answer (score 3):

CTR+Shift worked for me.

(Works for Microsoft Office as well)

Comment: Thank you, that worked to take it out of "zoom without the CTRL key" for me

Answer (score 1):

I believe they consider this to be a feature, and I haven't found a way to turn it off.  I think it only happens if you are holding the control key while trying to use the mouse wheel, but I've found it gets locked in that mode sometimes.  Personally I think this feature is anoying as &^%% and I wish they would take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Accessibility settings, you might have "locked" it down my accident

Under Windows 7 they are here:

Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center